# Linker errors in Objective-C++ Metal project

Tags: objective-c, macos, linker, objective-c++, metal

I am on El Capitan and I've created a new project through Xcode where I've chosen `OS X -> Application -> Game (Language: Objective-C, Game Technology: Metal)`

The project compiles and runs without problems initially.

Then I rename the main view controller `GameViewController.m` to `GameViewController.mm` to use Objective-C++. When I build now, I get the following linker errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>    "_MTKMetalVertexDescriptorFromModelIO", referenced from:
>        -[GameViewController _loadAssets] in GameViewController.o
>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MDLMesh", referenced from:
>        objc-class-ref in GameViewController.o
>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MTKMesh", referenced from:
>        objc-class-ref in GameViewController.o
>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MTKMeshBufferAllocator", referenced from:
>        objc-class-ref in GameViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

I've tried wrapping Metal headers into `extern "C" {}` though that didn't help.

How can I make it to build?

Comment: Looks like you're missing MetalKit(?).  Try adding it to the Frameworks section of the target settings and see if that helps.

Comment: I thought that won't work, since it compiled well with a ".m" file. But yes, after changing to ".mm" and adding MetalKit, Metal and ModelIO it compiles again. @KirkSpaziani - would you mind adding an answer to the question so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: When I renamed `GameViewController.m` to `GameViewController.mm` I got: `use of '@import' when modules are disabled`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that Objective-C has a relatively new feature whereby including a header automatically adds the framework to your link command. The Apple supplied template projects have that feature enabled by default. Hence the list of frameworks in your build settings is empty. By changing the language to Objective-C++ you've walked away from that feature and have to manually add the framework.

Comment: The name of the setting is "'Link Frameworks Automatically" and it does not solve the problem even if it stays active. (It is true that I changed other settings, like C++ language dialect to C++ 17)